# two scripts doing the same thing

Tags: jquery, jsonp

I have a script which allows to display Bing search results: [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dVqwD/54/)

I want to paginate this script which means setting a div which on click will do a second request only this time showing the next amount of results. I know this has to be changed:

```
var WebCount = "Web.Count=12";
var WebOffset = "Web.Offset=0";
```

The second reqeust would look like:

```
var WebCount = "Web.Count=12";
var WebOffset = "Web.Offset=1";
```

And so on.

I also know that the function doSearch should be renamed for the second request (ea doSearch2)

So my question is what else should I change to perform a second request? 
I'm trying not to copy the same script and changing all the (function) names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to duplicate the search function to show the second page. Just update the value of the variable `WebOffset` and run `doSearch`. Or add an Offset parameter to the function:

```
function doSearch(search,validate,offset){
    WebOffset = "Web.Offset="+offset;
    ...
```

Look here for an example: http://jsfiddle.net/Tz6wC/

(Note: I removed some stuff from your code that is not necessary for this example)

Comment: Im not getting this..It seems to me I would still have to copy the script for every second request. What do you mean by update? You mean update it with the click of a div(html)?

Comment: I just realized...wait a minute, Im trying this

Comment: No luck so far, can you please elaborate?

Comment: Is this what you mean:     `$("#page2").click(function() {
    var WebOffset = "Web.Offset=1";    
    var searchTerms = getSearch();
        doSearch(searchTerms);
    });`

Comment: Yes, basically this is what I mean

Comment: The main problem with your code is, that you do not assign a new value to the existing variable WebOffset but define a new local variable, that is only visible inside the click handler function. Remove the var keyword to fix this. See the example in my posting...

Comment: Thanks, I accepted answer:) (Can you explain why the first result of the second page is in fact the last of the previous page??)